# How to block access for a user who has been deleted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The remote user uses the API for which authorization is needed, and passes it successfully.

Created an Asp Core Web API project, I use Identity to control access, deleted a user through UserManager.DeleteAsync:

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDbContext<CommonDBContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQL")));


            services.AddScoped<IFamilyRepository, FamilyRepository>()
                    .AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>();

            services.AddIdentity<UserEntity, RoleEntity>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddUserManager<UserManagerExtensions>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CommonDBContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
            });
            app.UseMiddleware<TestMiddelwwre>();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

- **Expected Result**: A user who has been deleted cannot use the action with `[Authorize]` attributes.
- **Actual result**: the user successfully passes Authentication and Authorization

Comment: how did you "delete" the user? is it setting custom flag like `IsDeleted`..? is there any [`IsApproved`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved?view=netframework-4.8) field on the user model? if yes, set the `IsApproved` to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default authorization middleware validates the access token supplied - be it a cookie or bearer token - and simply decodes the information encoded therein, which can be out of sync with changes to the user that occurred after the token was issued. It does not check the current state of the user back in the database. If you want this functionality, you will have to add it to the authorization middleware. Please note that this means an additional trip to the database, so use it wisely - might want to invoke this only on certain critical endpoints and leave the default policy everywhere else, but thats up to you.

When you configure your authorization, you can add an authorization policy that requires a user that "is not deleted" (in my example i added a policy called "ActiveUserPolicy"), or edit the default policy to require this.

One way to achieve this is via authorization requirements & requirement handler. The main advantage of this is that it allows dependency injection into the requirement handlers, so you can do whatever you want with registered services. Here is a short example.

You will need an authorization requirement class, lets say `ActiveUserRequirement`. It simple needs to extend the `IAuthorizationRequirement` interface

```
 public class ActiveUserRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement {}
```

Then you will need the handler

```
public class ActiveUserRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ActiveUserRequirement>
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    // UserManager<TUser> available via dependency injection. U can inject anything you want
    public ActiveUserRequirementHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ActiveUserRequirement requirement)
    {            
        var userFromDb = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        // Check whatever qualifies as a deleted user in your usecase.
        if (userFromDb != null && userFromDb.EmailConfirmed) // user exists in db, & we confirmed their email
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
            // calling .Fail() is not recommended, the framework assumes a requirement has failed automatically if no handler explicitly says it passed.
            // this allows multiple requirement handlers to have their own way of determining whether a requirement has passed
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need is to register this with your authorization middleware.

```
// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ....

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ActiveUserPolicy", policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new ActiveUserRequirement());
            });
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ActiveUserRequirementHandler>();

}
```

With this setup, you can add a `[Authorize(Policy = "ActiveUserPolicy")]` attribute to your controllers, or actions.

If you with this to work simply with `[Authorize]`, then you might need to change the default authorization policy. yo can simply set this up as follows:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy =
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddRequirements(new ActiveUserRequirement())
                .Build();
        }
```

Make sure you call `app.UseAuthorization()` right after `app.AddAuthentication()` to ensure the authorization middleware is applied.

Also read [Policy based authorization from the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to learn more on this.